# How can I have a playbook initiate other playbooks, based on user input?

Tags: ansible

I would like to have a starter playbook, say `go.yml` -- and within this, I would like to be able to prompt the user for which products they would like to perform actions on (say `proxy`, `lb`, etc.).

Is there a way I can query the user for input, and then based on that input initiate playbooks? Basically, I want something like the following:

```
- hosts: "prod"
  sudo: yes
  vars_prompt:
    product: "What product do you want to deploy?"
  if product == proxy:
       - include proxy.yml
  if product == lb:
       - include lb.yml
    ...
```

I'm not very comfortable with how playbooks flow, and how they differ distinctly from task/handler files. Is anything like this possible? My goal is to avoid having a dozen different playbook files to choose from, and instead just have a default initiation type playbook which can always be used.

Answer (score 1):

A playbook can include other playbooks. So you can have multiple playbooks which are triggered through a single entry point playbook. But on playbook level there are not conditions. All included playbooks will be executed.

Your conditions on roles theoretically would work. The correct syntax would be:

```
roles:
  - role: proxy
    when: product == "proxy"
  - role: lb
    when: product == "lb"
```

But this is kind of re-inventing the wheel. To limit which roles should be executed one usually uses [tags](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_tags.html) (and skip-tags).

```
roles:
  - role: proxy
    tags: proxy
  - role: lb
    tags: lb
```

Then, for example, call you playbook with `--tags "proxy"`. This also works with included playbooks.

The downside of using vars_prompt and conditions on roles is, you'll get tons of skipped tasks when executing the playbook. When filtered by tag the non-matching roles/tasks will not be shown with a skipped state.